# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda' joblib

Tags: path, anaconda

I globally conda installed the joblib module using a Mac OS X, Mojave, with anaconda3:

```
conda install -c anaconda joblib
```

After the installation

```
conda --version
```

returns:

```
File "/Users/julia/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
 from conda.cli import main
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

I have read about this generic error of not finding conda, located my ~/anaconda3/bin and exported it as a path to my .bashrc to fix the error. However, this didn't help. Is there any chance I can still fix my anaconda?

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

This is very annoying, since I was so stupid to do it to my global anaconda, not just some virtual env.

Typing "python" still works and finds python, but all the modules seem to be gone. It now says eg. No module named 'pandas' etc.

Thank you!